# spark-submit - cannot pickle class in package, but can pickle 'same' class in root folder

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, protocol-buffers

In my Python-based Spark task 'main.py', I reference a protobuf generated class 'a_pb2.py'. If I place all files in the root directory like

```
/
- main.py
- a_pb2.py
```

and zip a_pb2.py into 'proto.zip', then run

```
spark-submit --py-files=proto.zip main.py
```

everything runs as expected.

However, if I move the protobuf classes to a package, organizing my files like

```
/
- main.py
- /protofiles
  - __init__.py
  - a_pb2.py
```

and zip /protofiles into 'proto.zip', then run

```
spark-submit --py-files=proto.zip main.py
```

the spark task fails, saying it cannot pickle class Account within a_pb2

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
>       process()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 272, in dump_stream
>       bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 451, in dumps
>       return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
>   _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle class 'a_pb2.Account': import of module 'a_pb2' failed

I am assuming this class serialization is happening to distribute the dependencies to worker nodes. But wouldn't this serialization also happen in the initial case, and if the class was unpickle-able, it should fail then as well? Needless to say I am confused, and not familiar with the nuances of how spark treats dependency packages+modules vs just modules.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Worth also noting, I tried the failing situation but replaced the protobuf-generated module with a basic no-op module and things worked fine.

Comment: Hey Jamie, How did you fix this ?? I am stuck with a similar issue.

Comment: @GolakSarangi I also ran into this, my only workaround was to follow Jamie's approach and zip all my protos into a flat zip file.