# ModuleNotFoundError because PySpark serializer is not able to locate library folder

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have the following folder structure

```
 - libfolder
    - lib1.py
    - lib2.py
 - main.py
```

`main.py` calls `libfolder.lib1.py` which then calls `libfolder.lib2.py` and others.

It all works perfectly fine in local machine but after I deploy it to Dataproc I get the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 455, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libfolder'
```

I have zipped the folder into `xyz.zip` and run the following command:

```
spark-submit --py-files=xyz.zip main.py
```

The serializer is not able to find the location for `libfolder` . Is there a problem with the way i am packaging my folders?

This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540313/spark-submit-cannot-pickle-class-in-package-but-can-pickle-same-class-in-ro) but it's not answered.

**Edit:** response to Igor's questions

unzip -l for the zip file returns the following

```
 - libfolder
    - lib1.py
    - lib2.py
 - main.py
```

In main.py lib1.py is called with this import statement

```
from libfolder import lib1
```

Comment: May you list content of the zip file (`unzip -l xyz.zip`) and show how exactly `main.py` calls `libfolder.lib1.py` in the code?

Comment: Also please include how do you invoke dataproc?

Comment: You are running this command from which folder?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$ cat main.py

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

from subpkg import sub

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Shell Count")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

text_file = sc.textFile("file:///etc/passwd")
counts = text_file.map(lambda line: sub.map(line)) \
    .map(lambda shell: (shell, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: sub.reduce(a, b))

counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///count5.txt")

$ cat subpkg/sub.py

def map(line):
  return line.split(":")[6]

def reduce(a, b):
  return a + b

$ unzip -l /tmp/deps.zip 
Archive:  /tmp/deps.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-01-07 14:22   subpkg/
        0  2019-01-07 13:51   subpkg/__init__.py
       79  2019-01-07 14:13   subpkg/sub.py
---------                     -------
       79                     3 files


$ gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster test-cluster main.py --py-files deps.zip
Job [1f0f15108a4149c5942f49513ce04440] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
Hello world!
Job [1f0f15108a4149c5942f49513ce04440] finished successfully.
```

Comment: It works fine for noop scripts. I get the above error only if I use spark's reduce method

Comment: Hmm, the trivial word-count program also works for me if I pull out map/reduce functions into another module. Could you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass zip file using **--py-files** parameter in **spark-submit**. You just need to import the package where UDF function resides in your python project
For example:

```
from package1.subpackage1.UDFPythonFile1 import UDF1
```

Package1 is directory where you are executing your entry point python script (main.py)

> - main.py
> - package1
>
>   - subpackage1
>
>     - UDFPythonFile1.py

Advantage of implementing above approach is to avoid creating zip file every time. This has worked for me on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me works writing the `py-files` in quote.

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --verbose --deploy-mode client \
  --py-files "dependencies.zip" $HOME/jobs/master/etl_master.py
```

Also remember the order of the arguments, I would recommend first to add `--verbose` after that submit again the job and look at the log to find the arguments your program is passing thought the server.