# Python module dependencies on cloud-dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

i am trying to deploy my code on cloud-dataproc.
My app is made of two modules, moduleA.py and moduleB.py
moduleA import a function from modulB
I have uploaded both modules in the same bucket, however when i kick off my dataproc template , dataproc complains that it cannot find moduleB
WHat extra steps do i need to follow in order for my moduleA to see moduleB on dataproc?

kind regards

Comment: Could you share how you're invoking Dataproc? And perhaps how the modules are declared?

Comment: This answer has lots of details on declaring and importing modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863576

Comment: Hello, Thanks for getting back. so, i have two modules ,  main.py and external.py all stored in my gs://mybucket. main.py has this import                                          from exernal import extenal_function                                             i have setup a template that i am using to invoke dataproc, and this is the command line i have attempted - with no success --

Comment: gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://mm_dataproc/quixote_sorted.py --step-id=quixo --py-files gs://mm_dataproc/external.py --workflow-template=quixote_dtp_template_5 -- gs://mm_dataproc/donquixote.txt

Comment: Could you include error in the post? And also how the modules are declared?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to all..I think I had some other unrelated errors in one of the steps I thought I deleted it, nothing to do with dependencies
Managed to have a successful run by packaging dependencies in a zip and run with.  --py-files gs://mydeps.zip .....

Kind regards