# GCP Dataproc: How to submit an entire directory to pyspark Job using console/python/rest api

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-dataproc

Let's say I have a structure like the following:

[image: directory structure]

`runner.py` is my main entry point that I provide to the Dataproc job. This in turns imports and calls `gcp_pyspark_test2.py`. Currently I provide it as Additional python files in job submission. But my actual use case has multiple folder hierarchies. Is there a way to bundle it all up and only reference the top level directory (source root). You can assume that it is in the same structure on google storage bucket as it is on local. I am having a little difficulty in understanding how Dataproc resolves paths. In a local setup you will set the source root as part of your python path and then reference everything underneath it from there. But I don't know how to set that up for Dataproc. Any help is deeply appreciated.

UPDATE:

I am also ok with passing the files as python_file_uris. The main issue is that dataproc does not recognize the structure. In this scenario I am passing the `gs://my-test-bucket/gcp_test/test_inner/gcp_pyspark_test2.py` as a python file but cannot import it in the runner either as `gcp_test.test_inner.gcp_pyspark_test2` or as `test_inner.gcp_pyspark_test2`

UPDATE2:

I was able to get it to work by passing `gcp_test.zip` as pyfiles and then referencing `gcp_test.test_inner.gcp_pyspark_test2` in my runner file. This is what's throwing me off. From other answers online and how python works, the zip file should be my source root folder so I should be able to reference `test_inner.gcp_pyspark_test2` but that import does not work. I can also see that the zip file is added to the python path on the cluster - `['/tmp/7c09ec5d-d6cf-4834-b6aa-6a26814e386x', '/tmp/7c09ec5d-d6cf-4834-b6aa-6a26814e386x/gcp_test.zip']`

Can anyone explain what's going on. Thanks

Comment: How about installing your code as a python package on all your workers ? Your runner.py would then only need to import the package and run your code

Comment: So build up the whole thing as a wheel and install it on the cluster? Is there no easier way? I was hoping that I wouldn't have to fiddle around with my cluster or ssh into it

Comment: It's actually considered as "best practice". Another way involves using docker files but the idea is essentially the same: prepare your environment on the cluster workers and have a very basic runner script.

Comment: could you point me to some resources online that detail how to do this. I am still new to cloud and spark world. Thanks again for your help

Comment: This question appears to have been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863576

Comment: @tix thanks, it did help but I still have an anomaly that I have updated my question with. If you can provide some light that will be great. Thanks

Comment: Do you zip gcp_test or its contents? When you open the zip file, do you see gcp_test?

Comment: I zipped the directory itself as in when I unzip it I see the directory gcp_test which has the content underneath it. Do I need to zip the contents instead?

Comment: That seemed to work and it makes sense. The zip file is the root. Thanks!!