# pyspark: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' because PySpark serializer is not able to locate paython package folder 'app'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

I am reading a csv into dataframe in PySpark using below code snippet.

project structure:

```
 pyspark-debug:
   app
     __init__.py
     data-pipeline.py
   main.py
   ....
```

data-pipeline.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import Row


def row_wise_transformation(row: Row):
    return row # need to implement some transformation here.


def test_data_pipeline():
    spark_session = (
        SparkSession.builder
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("pyspark-debug")
            .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
            .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false")  # make it true when run on prod
            .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
            .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "4GB")
            .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", 15 * 60)
            .config("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false")
            .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", '15000')
            .getOrCreate()
    )
    file_path = "file:///Users/mohdnayyar/Downloads/color_srgb.csv" # change path accordingly
    df: DataFrame = spark_session.read.text(file_path)
    transform_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row_wise_transformation(row)).toDF() # this map api causing error
    transform_df.show(truncate=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data_pipeline()
```

main.py

```
from app.data_pipeline import test_data_pipeline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data_pipeline()
```

One can download the sample csv file from [here](https://wsform.com/knowledgebase/sample-csv-files/).

when I am running data-pipeline.py directly using spark-submit, its worsking fine. But when I tried to run main.py file using spark-submit getting an serialization error as below

```
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 587, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 74, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 458, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

my spark-submit command as follow:

```
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--name "L1_L2_DATA_PIPELINE" \
--master local \
--packages org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3-bundle_2.12:0.9.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0 \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \
--py-files pyspark-debug.zip \
pyspark-debug/main.py
```

This quesiton is similiar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901591/pyspark-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-app), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010189/modulenotfounderror-in-pyspark-caused-in-serializers-py), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863576/modulenotfounderror-because-pyspark-serializer-is-not-able-to-locate-library-fol), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741832/pyspark-custom-udf-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named) etc.

Most of the answer is to create a dependency jar and provide it in --py-files as --py-files dependency.zip. But doest not work for me, still getting the same error.